# How to eliminate certain annoying message during framework source code debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

While debugging the framework source code I always get this annoying message from the studio:

> Some bytes have been replaced with the
>   Unicode substitution character while
>   loading file
>   C:\Users\markk\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\src\source.NET\4\DEVDIV_TFS\Dev10\Releases\RTMRel\ndp\fx\src\Core\Microsoft\Scripting\Compiler\VariableBinder.cs\1305376\VariableBinder.cs
>   with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding. Saving
>   the file will not preserve the
>   original file contents.

As a result, the source code is open in modified mode (with an asterisk in the name). This is hugely annoying.

Does anyone know how to make it go away? I am using VS2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Looked like a good answer.  Do you need anything else?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I need to verify it. Right now, I am not in the right context to do that. I will surely mark it as answer once I actually verify it.

Comment: I am having the same issue and have performed numerous searches to no avail.

Comment: where is the answer? I found this is marked as a fixed bug in vs2010:
[link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550886)

Comment: There was indeed an answer, but like I said in the comment, I had to shift my attention to something else and did not have the time to validate it. Now, the answer disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

It seems a vs2010 bug. I tried but i cannot reproduce it.

This maybe could be a easy workaround:

go to visual studio option --> Debugging

in the general options you should uncheck 
"Require source files to exactly match the original version"

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into similar issue and found a way to fix it:

1. Open "Region" from Control Panel
2. Choose "Administrative" tab
3. Check if "Language for non-Unicode programs" is any UTF-8 or Unicode language that other than English (In my case it is Chinese). If so, click "Change system locale..." to change it to English.

It then works after locale change and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the file encoding to UTF-8 outside of VS2010.

Answer (score -5):

You should be able to turn off the message (or any other message) by using the Debug > Exceptions dialog. If it's not there you can add it to the menu or use Quick Access in the Productivity Power Tools. With the Exceptions dialog you can turn off exceptions when they are thrown or unhandled. You can add your own exceptions if your exception isn't in the list.

[MSDN: How to: Break When an Exception is Thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx)